# Exclude category only on front page Wodpress query

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need exclude category from query only on front page. 
But category excluded on every pages. 
This is my code in functions.php:

```
function remove_category( $query ) {

if ( $query->is_front_page()  ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-32075' );
}   
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_category' );
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90923/pre-get-posts-for-exclude-category

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    if ( is_page('slug-of-page') && isset($query) ) {
        $query->set('cat', '-3');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

or

```
function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home ) {
$query->set( 'cat', '-5' );
}
return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanx all for answers, fixed
I replaced:

```
 $query->is_front_page()
```

with:

```
 is_front_page()
```

or

```
 is_page('home')
```

if your default page is blogpage then use is_home()

and now it works fine!